# Deleting last row from UITableView - Crash with NSInternalInconsistencyError

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've tried all searchable solutions to no avail. My current deletion code is as follows:

```
[self.conversationsTableView beginUpdates];
[_conversations removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
if ([self.conversationsTableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] == 1) {
    [self.conversationsTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
} else {
    [self.conversationsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
[self.conversationsTableView endUpdates];
```

As you can see, I am properly deleting from my datasource in _conversations before deleting the section/row - and I am also deleting the section if it's the last one.

I still get the crash:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'

I'm out of ideas, unless I do a really hacky solution where I insert an invisible section above my actual content, which I really don't want to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what my numberOfSectionsInTableView looks like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

**Really weird update**: I tried to do a hacky way of getting around this by inserting a blank section as I deleted the old one. But for some unexplainable reason I am STILL getting the error. The error insists that the tableview has a new section count of 0 even though I've changed my code to the following:

```
if ([self.conversationsTableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.row] == 1) {
    [self.conversationsTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.conversationsTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
} else {
    [self.conversationsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Completely clueless as to why this is happening at this point...

Stack trace:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b6bee65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b137deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b6becca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010ad844de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000109bef679 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _computeSectionUpdates] + 2858
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000109c00059 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport initWithTableView:updateItems:oldRowData:newRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] + 435
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001098cf912 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 12936
    7   WontBuyIOS                          0x000000010819dea8 -[WOBMessagesViewController queryControllerDidChangeContent:] + 88
    8   LayerKit                            0x0000000108db4ca6 __65-[LYRQueryController updateWithObjectIdentifiers:changedObjects:]_block_invoke154 + 74
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c05249b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c03bc3c _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 284
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c05249b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c03a2af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b61ed09 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5e02c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5df828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e33cad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001097a4610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    18  WontBuyIOS                          0x00000001081a6bcf main + 111
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c08692d start + 1
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
 )
```

Insert/Deletion Code:

```
- (void)queryController:(LYRQueryController *)controller
        didChangeObject:(id)object
            atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
          forChangeType:(LYRQueryControllerChangeType)type
           newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch (type) {
        case LYRQueryControllerChangeTypeInsert: {
            [_conversations addObject:object];
            [self.conversationsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ newIndexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
            break;
        case LYRQueryControllerChangeTypeDelete: {
            [_conversations removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if ([self.conversationsTableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.row] == 1) {
                [self.conversationsTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                [self.conversationsTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            } else {
                [self.conversationsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to delete a section from the table, you need to update the data source data such that `numberOfSections` will now return one less section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately was an issue with another view controller which used a queryController. After fixing that view controller by making sure rows were properly deleted, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfRowsInSection` calls `_conversations.count`. After deleting the item in the data source array it returns a wrong value. Compare with `0` rather than `1`

`beginUpdates / endUpdates` is not needed for a single insert/delete/move operation.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it - your logic is sound but for some reason, UITableView will cache the value for numberOfRowsInSection. So I still need to compare with 1. Regardless, the call to deleteSections is definitely getting called with breakpoints to confirm - it's still giving me the inconsistency error.

Answer (score 0):

I thing @rmaddy is right you should update the `numberOfSections` data source and return 1 less section.
Have you tried calling `[tableView reloadData]` instead.

Comment: I've tried this already - I have numberOfSections return 1 if there are objects in my datasource and 0 if not. I don't want to use reloadData because I want to keep the animation.

Comment: Does it still show same error after you have set it to 1

Comment: You can try this add a check to make sure there are at least 2 sections in the tableView before removing a section and then if there only 1 section left then remove the row which is left instead of removing the section.

Comment: I only use one section in my tableView though. Also, regardless of whether I have one section or not, if I call either deleteSection or deleteRows I get the same exact error.

Comment: Well if your using one section only then, just before you delete old the section add a new section to the table then remove the old section

Comment: I didn't try that yet because it felt like hack. Now something is really wrong, because I just tried to do that and I still get the same error. I INSERTED a section to replace my old one and it still says "old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'". How is this possible? I don't understand how my new section count can be 0 if I inserted a row. See my original post to see my code.

Comment: @EricGao add NSLog statements and see which method is last called before the app crashes

Comment: I posted the stack trace in the original post. As far as I can tell, the farthest I can get is [self.conversationsTableView endUpdates], which I call after deleting. For reference, queryControllerDidChangeContent triggers the deletion as my dataSource is telling me that something was removed.

Comment: @EricGao is this error occurring even if you have more then 1 sections before you begin updating tableView

Comment: No, if I start off with a row/section in my tableView, I can delete the row fine. Then as soon as insert a new row/delete it, the error occurs. Or, if I start off with no rows, insert something, then delete it, it also crashes with the same error.

Comment: @EricGao could you post the code of adding of new rows which have you implemented and in which method have you implemented it

Comment: I just tried another hack... I add an invisible section to the bottom of my tableView that is always there - I am STILL getting the inconsistency error. I have no idea what's going on anymore, as it seems like the tableview is not even considering my code anymore.

Comment: Seems like there is some problem in your implementation or logic 
I made a new project with the code you wrote and it worked. 
 Here is the link to the code https://gist.github.com/shrijitsingh99/4814dc63c25fa25022c3  
If the issue is still not resolved post all the UITableView delegate and datasource methods you have implemented

Comment: Really appreciate all your help so far. I'll try to rewrite it later - there's one difference and it's that I am using a UIViewController with a tableView IBOutlet instead of a UITableViewController. Could that affect anything?

Comment: No that won't affect it.
Try implementing the code to delete rows when you click a tableview cell accessory, like in the link i posted.
It may be possible the error is being cause by the method which is implementing the code to delete rows i.e


    -(void)queryController:(LYRQueryController *)controller
        didChangeObject:(id)object
            atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
          forChangeType:(LYRQueryControllerChangeType)type
           newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath

Comment: Ok... it still doesn't work. But I found something strange. I used a prebuilt table view that builds correctly here: https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS. But when I use it in mine, I get the exact same error again. https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS/blob/master/Code/Controllers/ATLConversationListViewController.m. See that link to see the code - I did not change any of it, I just moved it into my project and integrated it. When I build their sample project, I can delete fine. It fails on my project. Why could this be?

Comment: Oh my god, I think I fixed it. It didn't have to do with my ConversationTableViewController at all - my messageTableViewController was the one that was generating these errors. Both view controllers implement a queryController so I couldn't tell which one was causing the problem. Thanks for all the help Shrijit.

Comment: @EricGao No problem. Glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like calling `numberOfRowsInSection:` has a side effect. Use `_conversations.count` instead in your `if` condition. That should fix your first original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `[self.conversationsTableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.row]` and passing in indexPath.row. That is incorrect and should be `[indexPath section]`.